# Cancelling elements of a list under a certain value

Tags: c, list

I need to delete elements minor of a value from a list.

I am using this function for cancelling nodes with key < average.
The problem is that when i print the list after deleting, i get an infinite loop because the pointer doesnt seem to become NULL, but for exiting the function, it has to be NULL.

```
void Cancel_Node(struct node *head , int average){
    struct node *temp;
    temp = head;
    struct node *prox = temp->next;
    while(temp !=NULL && prox != NULL){
       if(temp->key <= average){
            prox = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = prox;
        }
        else{
            prox=temp->next;
            temp= temp->next;   
        }   
    }
}
```

Thats the struct, it's a classic linked list:

```
struct node{
    int key;
    struct node *next;
};
```

It works fine, if i print before cancelling, i get all the list without errors, then if i call cancel and then i try to print, i get an infinite loop because head!= NULL is never fulfilled, but i dont get why. It is probably an easy problem but im stucked

Comment: Re "*i get an infinite loop because the pointer doesnt seem to become NULL*", I believe that's because of an error elsewhere. Note that you don't properly delete the node from the list because the previous node in the list still points to the freed node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this is a great time to use double pointers. We free nodes by keeping a pointer to the next pointer rather than a pointer to the node like so:

```
void Cancel_Node(struct node **head , int average){
    while(*head){
       if(head[0]->key <= average){
            struct node *temp = *head;
            *head = temp->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        else{
            head = &head[0]->next;
        }   
    }
}
```

Your algorithm can trash itself because the edge cases aren't handled correctly, probably causing the infinite loop behavior you noticed. The easiest way to deal with the problem is to remove the edge cases; the double pointer solution doesn't have any edge cases.

Comment: Hi mate! it worked but i needed to remove * from *head=&head[0]->next; i am not sure why tho

Comment: @AnotherStudent: Because it was a typo on my part. Fixed.