# Automatically set pointers to NULL after free

Tags: c, void-pointers, double-pointer

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58045409) post shows a way to use `void**`s to eliminate a category of bugs related to dangling pointers (use after free, double free, etc):

```c
void freep(void **p) {
    if (p) {
        free(*p);
        *p = NULL;
    }
}
```

I tried it out with the following driver code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define free(x) freep(x)

int main(void) {
    char *s = malloc(5);
    strcpy(s, "hehe");

    char **ss = &s;

    free(s);
    free(ss);
    free(&s);
}
```

As noted in the post and its comments, it is technically in violation of the C standard - compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c17`, I get warnings regarding passing `char*` and `char**` type parameters to a `void**` type parameters.

My question is, can it be made to not violate the C standard, while still achieving its goal of avoiding dangling pointers by ensuring the user can't forget to set a pointer to `NULL` after `free()`-ing it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Implement it as a macro?

Comment: Your code doesn't have any allocations so it shouldn't `free` anything. Also, freeing `x` and freeing `*x` are completely different things, so your `#define` will lead to massive errors.

Comment: Apologies, I was focusing on demonstrating the fact that passing a `char*`/`char**` type parameter to a `void**` type parameter raised a compiler warning.

Comment: OT: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1879469/4386427

Comment: `free(ss);` and `free(&s);` were leftovers from my experimentations regarding what I can pass to a `void**` type parameter - since I can pass any pointer to a `void*` type parameter, I thought I might be able to pass any pointer / double pointer to `void**`. I thought I'd keep it around, since I was focusing on the types I'm passing around, rather than the semantics of what can be `free()`'d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`freep` can only set a `void *` to `NULL`. You presumably want to set a variety of pointer types (including `char *`) to `NULL`.

The only way `freep` would work is if you did

```c
void *p = s;
freep( &p );
s = p;
```

Of course, that's ridiculous.

An ordinary function won't do because different pointer types can have different sizes and layouts. Solution:

```c
#define free( p ) do { free( p ); p = NULL; } while ( 0 )

free( s );
```

Warning: The above evaluates the argument expression twice. It's better to use a name that makes it clear this is a macro rather than overridding `free`.

```c
#define SAFE_FREE( p ) do { free( p ); p = NULL; } while ( 0 )

SAFE_FREE( s );
```

Comment: 'SAFE_FREE(cond ? ptr1 : ptr2);' gives "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment" in expansion of macro ‘SAFE_FREE’

Comment: @yvs2014 Garbage In, Garbage Out. Use `if ( cond ) SAFE_FREE( ptr1 ); else SAFE_FREE( ptr2 );` (And all the more reason not to call it `free`.)

Comment: "if ( cond ) SAFE_FREE( ptr1 ); else SAFE_FREE( ptr2 );" it means that one cannot automatically replace free() with SAVE_FREE() without editing code. And it's possible to find another reasons against macros, what I can remember it's undetectable redirection made with macros for example for autoconf's AC_SEARCH_LIBS(fn,...), like with res_xxx on MacOS

Comment: @yvs2014 Re "*it means that one cannot automatically replace free() with SAVE_FREE() without editing code*", And that's why it isn't called `free`. I've already explained they're not equivalent, and suggested using a different name for that very reason.

Comment: "that's why it's called free" got it:) then maybe it's a good reason for "UNSAFE_FREE" naming

Comment: @yvs2014, Sorry, That was supposed to be "isn't called". Already fixed. /// I didn't come up with the name `SAFE_FREE`. (It's used by MS, IIRC.) It's safer than a normal `free` because you get a protection violation if you use the freed pointer. That's its reason for being.

Answer (score 2):

The only generic object pointer type that C supports is `void*`. This special ability of `void*` does *not* apply recursively to `void**`. Passing a `char**` to a function expecting a `void**` is invalid C like the compiler told you with a warning/error.

Therefore the only correct use of the `freep` function in your question is this:

```
char *s = malloc(5);
void* vptr = s;
freep(&vptr);
```

And then we can see why `freep` is problematic - the bad `void**` API means that `s` is still a dangling pointer because only `vptr` points to null now. Just forgot about this function, it was a bad idea and poorly implemented.

A call for sanity is to forget all about that function and instead write readable standard C:

```c
free(s);
s = NULL;
```

There exists no reason why you can't write this instead of designing some bad API bloat function as an abstraction layer over 2 lines of readable C code.

A macro would work too, but it's good practice to avoid mysterious macros over well-known standard C.

Comment: I agree replacing a two-liner with a macro is not the greatest idea, but for this question I'm putting that aside and focusing more on improving the use case of `void**`s as shown in the original question.

Comment: @404NameNotFound The correct approach is probably not to build a dedicated abstraction layer on top of the low-level malloc/free, but rather to build an abstraction layer around them while writing the application-specific code. That's how C programs are normally written.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do the job:

```
#define freep(p) {free(p); p=NULL;}
```

Comment: macros can be tricky if they're applied directly, like 'if (cond) free(ptr); else smth;' works, but 'if (cond) freep(ptr); else smth;' doesn't

Answer (score 1):

As a special case, C specifies that there are automatic conversions between `void *` and all other object-pointer types.  This is not any kind of pattern, but rather a provision specifically for type `void *`.  That is, there is no analogous special case for `void **`.

You can manually (via typecast) convert among different object pointer types, such as between `char **` and `void **`.  Some compilers may even provide such conversions implicitly, which constitutes a language extension.  But writing through such a converted pointer violates the strict aliasing rule, producing undefined behavior.<sup>*</sup>

Overall, no, you cannot make a function of type `void f(void **)` serve as a general-purpose function for freeing memory and setting pointers to `NULL`.  Alternatives include:

- use a macro instead:

  ```
  #define free(p) do { free(p); p = NULL; } while (0)
  ```
- pass an additional argument that conveys the pointer's actual target type:

  ```
  enum target_type { VOID, CHAR, INT, DOUBLE };
  void freep(void *pp, enum target_type type) {
      switch (type) {
          case VOID: {
              void **p = (void **) pp;
              free(*p);
              *p = NULL;
              break;
          }
          case CHAR: {
              char **p = (char **) pp;
              free(*p);
              *p = NULL;
              break;
          }
          case INT: {
              int **p = (int **) pp;
              free(*p);
              *p = NULL;
              break;
          }
          case DOUBLE: {
              double **p = (double **) pp;
              free(*p);
              *p = NULL;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Of course, this requires you to choose in advance which pointer types are supported, so it is not altogether general.  But if you want something like this then it might be a good use case for X macros to generate the enum definition and matching function implementation without so much boilerplate.
- In principle, you could also use a type-generic macro as a front end to multiple type-specific free-and-nullify functions, but I don't see much reason to prefer that over both the preceding options.  If you're ok with a macro, then the former is much simpler, and if you're not then you're not.

---

<sup>*</sup> One might argue that writing a `char *` through a `void **` -- `*voidpp = NULL` -- is an allowed case, given that `char *` and `void *` are required to have the same representation and alignment requirement, and are generally intended to be interchangeable. But even if one accepts that, it is (another) special case.  That does not address your question in its full generality.